# getting 404 error for bower components while the path is all set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to run my application using gulp task runner and i have installed few bower components and angular is one of them

When i try to run the application I am getting errors[image]

In index.html:

```
 <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-accessibility-plugin/plugins/js/bootstrap-accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-socialshare/dist/angular-socialshare.min.js"></script>
```

Project structure:
[image]

I have also included the path but still getting the same errors.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add  nodejs part where you defining the static path

Comment: I have already given you the path in index.js

Comment: please add the script in your post

Comment: just add ur project stucture.

Comment: @Srigar
I have added it

Comment: jsut place the bower_components inside the app folder.. Thats the problem. Change the bower download location in .bowerrc file also